# Increasing the maximum pipe size in linux

Tags: c, pipe

I would like to increase the maximum pipe size in linux.
I am not talking about F_SETPIPE_SZ... but it seems there is 1MB limit to the pipe size(depends on the linux version I guess)

Can anyone let me know how I can increase the max limit?

Comment: Maybe by updating a file in the `/proc` or `/sys` filesystems, or with a `sysctl`? I honestly don't know, but those places seems like they should be good starting points to look at.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I found the max size in /proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size, do I need to restart the system or something for the change to take effect?

Comment: Changing files in the `/proc` file system usually get in effect immediately, of the next time something happens (like creating a pipe). Rebooting would just restore the default value, so you might want to look at the `sysctl` properties as well as those can be changed in a configuration file that is loaded on boot.

Comment: I just found that max buffer size cannot be increased to 1GB for some reason, is there a hard limit to the buffer size?

Comment: If you want to transfer up or even over 1GB of data as a single packet then pipes are probably not the best IPC abstraction.  For that much data files are probably more appropriate. Or use some kind of protocol that allows you to split up the packets into smaller parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the value in /proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size, seems to do the trick :)... Thanks Joachim for your pointer in the right direction.

My current linux has the max value as 1048576