# Pipe gets stuck during write

Tags: c, operating-system, pipe

When I'm trying to write to one of my pipes to communicate with a child process, it gets stuck. My first guess was that it was because its buffer was full, and something has to read from it, for it to continue, so I followed [Increasing the maximum pipe size in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926617/increasing-the-maximum-pipe-size-in-linux) instructions, and to my surprise, my maximum buffer size is 1048576. I'm trying to write 160000 bytes into my pipe. I don't understand why it's getting stuck.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIZE 320000
#define FILENAME "Practical_Q_1numbers.txt"


extern long fun(long a, long b);

void write_numbers(int process_id,int* pipefds, long* numbers) {
    long process_numbers[SIZE / 8];
    memcpy(process_numbers, &numbers[SIZE / 8 * process_id], SIZE / 8 * sizeof(long));
    printf("This gets printed\n");
    // Pipe Limit
    write(pipefds[1], process_numbers, SIZE / 8 * sizeof(long));
    printf("This doesnt\n");
}


// Correct
long calculate(long* numbers, int left, int right) {
    if(left == right){
        return numbers[left];
    }else if(left + 1 == right) {
        return fun(numbers[left], numbers[right]);
    }
    int middle = (right + left) / 2;
    long l_ans = calculate(numbers, left, middle);
    long r_ans = calculate(numbers, middle + 1, right);
    return fun(l_ans, r_ans);
}

void calculateHelper(int id, int* pipefds) {
    long* ptr = (long*)malloc(SIZE / 8 * sizeof(long));
    read(pipefds[0], ptr, SIZE / 8 * sizeof(long));
    long res = calculate(ptr, 0, SIZE / 8 - 1);
    // write(pipefds[1], &res, sizeof(res));
    return;
}


int main() {
    // Read the file as parent.
    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen(FILENAME, "r");
    long* ptr = (long*)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(long));
    // Reads correctly
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        fscanf(myFile, "%ld", &ptr[i]);
    }
    int pipefds[8][2];
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        pipe(pipefds[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        write_numbers(i,pipefds[i], ptr);
        pid_t a = fork();
        if(a == 0) {
            // Child process
            calculateHelper(i,pipefds[i]);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    // Wait for your children to terminate
    while(wait(NULL) > 0);

    // long* finalContenders = (long*) malloc(8 * sizeof(long));

    // for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    //     read(pipefds[i][0], &finalContenders[i], sizeof(long));    
    // }

    // long ans = calculate(finalContenders, 0, 7);
    // printf("%ld\n",ans);
}
```

Fun is a function responsible for calculating the GCD of 2 numbers.

Comment: My max pipe size says it is 1MB but I've also had problems with pipes over about 10 - 100k. I think you're not supposed to use pipes for this much data.

Comment: Any alternatives I can use to send this much data to child processes?

Comment: Can you not use threads instead of processes? Then you have shared memory you can update in either thread.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is my homework to get familiar with different methods of Inter-Process Communication.

Comment: Then try sending the data in chunks. So your receiving process says got chunk_i gimmi chunk_i+1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    write_numbers(i,pipefds[i], ptr);
    pid_t a = fork();
    if(a == 0) {
        // Child process
        calculateHelper(i,pipefds[i]);
        exit(0);
    }
```

You write the data to the pipe *before* there's a process to read from it.  That's deadlock-prone no matter how large the *maximum* pipe buffer size might be.

This would be better:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    pid_t a = fork();
    if(a == -1) {
        // handle error
    }
    else if(a == 0) {
        // Child process
        calculateHelper(i,pipefds[i]);
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        write_numbers(i,pipefds[i], ptr);
    }
```

You'd also be better off writing smaller chunks to the pipe no matter what. Right now, [you don't handle partial `write()` results at all](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) (bolding mine):

> The `write()` function shall **attempt to write `nbyte` bytes** from the buffer pointed to by `buf` to the file associated with the open file descriptor, `fildes`.

There's no portable guarantee on *any* call to `write()` that the entirety of your requested buffer will be written.

The easiest way to do that is to create a `writeAllBytes()` wrapper around write, such as:

```
#define CHUNK_SIZE ( 4 * 1024 )

ssize_t writeAllBytes( int fd, void *data, size_t bytes )
{
    // need to do pointer arithmetic on the value so
    // it can't be a void *
    char *buf = data;

    ssize_t totalWritten = -1;

    while ( bytes > 0 )
    {
        size_t bytesToWrite = bytes;
        if ( bytesToWrite > CHUNK_SIZE )
        {
            bytesToWrite = CHUNK_SIZE;
        }

        ssize_t bytesWritten = write( fd, buf, bytesToWrite );
        if ( bytesWritten <= 0 )
        {
            break;
        }

        buf += bytesWritten;
        totalWritten += bytesWritten;
        bytes -= bytesWritten;
    }

    return( totalWritten );
}
```

Similarly, a corresponding `readAllBytes()` would also be appropriate.